# Azure using enterprise Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory

Before I am going to describe my questions, I would like to tell you that I am a web developer and not a security/Active Directory or Azure specialist, so please be gentle :-)

I work for a large international financial services company. We have a global IT department that provides member firms with services that we use (Active Directory 2012).

In my member firm, we are currently considering migrating custom build websites to Azure. All the custom build websites are implemented with Kerberos and Single Sign-On using Active Directory. Some of these websites read & write information in Active Directory.

The challenge that we are facing is how we can migrate these websites to Azure whilst using the enterprise's Active Directory. I searched for detailed information about solutions available but haven't found anything that answered my questions. My questions:

- What solutions are there for connecting Azure with an enterprise's Active Directory?
- What are the advantages and disadvantages for these solutions?
- What are the requirements for these solutions?

Perhaps there is a book/blog/whitepaper that answers my questions?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cannot use directly the corp AD from Azure. You must use Azure Active Directory. However, there are solution to keep the corp AD and the Azure AD in sync. For example read [Connecting AD and Azure AD: Only 4 clicks with Azure AD Connect](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/08/04/connecting-ad-and-azure-ad-only-4-clicks-with-azure-ad-connect.aspx), which shows how to use [Azure AD Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/site1164/program8612) to link the Azure AD with your corp AD. It will basically mirror **one corporate AD forest** with an Azure AD account, and keep it up to date by periodic re-sync. The net effect is that you develop your cloud apps to authenticate and authorize based on the Azure AD, but the Azure AD will mirror the corp AD. There will be a delay in propagating changes to Azure AD, eg. an employee added to the "domain\sales" group will not be allowed to access the "Sales" app for some hours until the Azure AD sync catches up with the corp AD change.